# Lucene Search 2 fields

Tags: lucene

I tried to search the best matching product (bounty paper towel) from a certain retailer, my query is the following, but the query returns 0 hit.

```
BooleanQuery.Builder combine = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

Query q1 = new QueryParser("product", new StandardAnalyzer()).parse(QueryParser.escape("product:" + "bounty paper towel"));
combine.add(q1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD); // find best name match

Query q2 = new QueryParser("retailer", new StandardAnalyzer()).parse(QueryParser.escape("retailer:" + "Target"));
combine.add(q2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); // Must from this retailer

searcher.search(combine.build(), hitsPerPage).scoreDocs;
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I build the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping things you don't want to escape.  You pass the string "product:bounty paper towel" to the `escape` method, which will escape the colon, which you don't want to escape.  In effect, that query, after escaping and analysis, will look like this:

> product:product\:bounty product:paper product:towels

You should escape the search terms, not the entire query.  Something like:

```java
parser.parse("product:" + QueryParse.escape("bounty paper towels"));
```

Also, it looks like you are looking for a phrase query there, in which case, it should be surrounded by quotes:

```java
parser.parse("product:\"" + QueryParse.escape("bounty paper towels") + "\"");
```

The way your building your boolean query looks fine.  You could leverage the query parser syntax to accomplish the same thing, if you prefer, like this:

```java
parser.parse(
    "product:\"" + QueryParse.escape("bounty paper towels") + "\""
    + "+retailer:" + QueryParse.escape("Target")
);
```

But again, there is nothing wrong with `BooleanQuery.Builder` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Used Lucene too many years ago, but let me try...

Rewrite you `parse` part as follow:

```
...
Query q1 = new QueryParser("product", new StandardAnalyzer())
            .parse("bounty paper towel");
...
Query q2 = new QueryParser("retailer", new StandardAnalyzer())
          .parse("Target"));
...
```

So your query should contain only target information, but not a column name - since it is already referenced before.